# Change Constraints constant on view load has no effect

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I have `UIPageViewController` that contains simple `UIViewController`s. The View of the VC contains an `UIImageView` (aspect fit) at the top and a UITextView at the bottom.
The LayoutConstraints for the ImageView are:

- Fixed Width: Which has an Outlet to the VCs-Class
- Fixed Height: Which has an Outlet to the VCs-Class
- Center X is equal to the superviews centerX
- Top is equal to Superviews MarinTop (+8)

The LayoutConstraints for the ImageView are:

- Top is equal to ImageView bottom
- Bottom is equal to superviews MarginBottom (+8)
- Width is equal superviews width (Multiplicator is 0.8)

This works as expected.

But when the VC is loaded and has the image to display, I want to change the size of the imageView. There is a minimum and a maximum size and if a image view is smaller or larger it needs to be resized. Otherwise the the imageview has to get the size of the image.

So I calculate the size for the actual image and set the constant for the two LayoutConstraints. The values are correct but the ImageView does not change.

I tried to set them in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but no change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see a warning in console where all constraints can't be simultaneously satisfied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try update your views inside viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
 // setup your constraints here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write your change constraint code in the below provided block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the vertical spacing between the ImageView and the textfield to be flexible (>=0). If that doesn't solve the issue, add:

```
[view setNeedsLayout];
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```

After you adjust the size of the imageview to size of the new image.